# Add text in Plotly.express

Tags: python, plotly

I have this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1,2,3,1,2,3],
              'department':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
               'revenue':[10,11,12,13,14,15]})
```

I plotted it using

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df,x=df.time,y=df.revenue,color=df.department)
fig.update_traces(mode='lines + markers',
             hovertemplate = 'Revenue: %{y:.d} <br>') 
             
fig.show()
```

I was able to have the 'revenue' showing up on the hover-template box but I also want to have the 'department' showing up too. However, I'm not really sure how to do this. Could somebody help me out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the data frame column is displayed in the hover box, so there is no need to play around with the template.

```
# fig.update_traces(mode='lines + markers',
             hovertemplate = 'Revenue: %{y:.d} <br>') 

fig.update_traces(mode='lines + markers')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add hover_name="department" as shown:

```
fig = px.line(df,x="time",y="revenue",color="department",hover_name="department")
```

Comment: I can see A and B outside the hover box for me.

Comment: oh. I would like to have them inside the hover box along with revenue